# Transparency of svg characters lost in illustrator

Tags: svg, character, transparency

I am writing simple svg code that looks like that:

```
<text x="100" y="100" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#111111" fill-opacity="0.1" font-family="arial" font-size="50">a</text>
<text x="150" y="100" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#111111" fill-opacity="0.5" font-family="arial" font-size="50">b</text>
<text x="200" y="100" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="#111111" fill-opacity="1" font-family="arial" font-size="50">c</text>
```

When I visualise it in Chrome, it looks perfect (different letters with different transparencies) but when I open it in Illustrator, all letters are black (no transparencies).

Any idea of what I can write so transparencies show in Illustrator ?

Thanks, 
Chris

Comment: Awesome Robert !! It works. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use opacity rather than fill-opacity to work around this issue in Illustrator.

Note that opacity is less performant than fill-opacity/stroke-opacity so only use it if you have to.